# Open a div by clicking a button, close the div by clicking outside only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have a button that opens and closes a div. I would like to improve this feature: I want the div to close also when pressing other than on div.
Is it possible to do this in CSS and HTML?

It's for the button 'top-bar-btn settings' :

EDIT

```
<div class="top-bar-btn" id="top-bar-btn">
  <button class="top-bar-btn create"
          title="Créer une nouvelle discussion">
          <!--(click)="onCreateChatWindow()">-->
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
  </button>


  <button class="top-bar-btn settings"
          title="Réglages"
          (click)="onSettingsChatWindow()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
  </button>
  <div id="outside" (click)="hide()"></div>

  <button class="top-bar-btn reduce"
          title="Réduire la fenêtre"
          (click) = "onReduceChatThreads()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
 <div class="settings-notification"
   id="settings-notification">
<div class="tr triangle">
  <div class="tr inner-triangle">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sound-signal">
  Signal sonore :
  <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal1" checked="checked">
  <label for="soundsignal1">Oui</label>
  <input type="radio" name="soundsignal" id="soundsignal2">
  <label for="soundsignal2">Non</label>
</div>

<div class="flash-signal">
  Signal visuel :
  <input type="radio" name="flashsignal" id="flashsignal1" checked="checked" (click)="flashSignal()">
  <label for="flashsignal1">Oui</label>
  <input type="radio" name="flashsignal" id="flashsignal2" (click)="notFlashSignal()">
  <label for="flashsignal2">Non</label>
</div>
```

>

```
#outside{
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:1;
}


hide(): void {
    document.getElementById('outside').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('settings-notification').style.display = 'none';
}

onSettingsChatWindow(): void {
    document.getElementById('outside').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('chat-threads').classList.toggle('display-settings');
}
```

I do not understand why it does not work.
This works only once and after the div no longer displays at all. Do you know why ?

Comment: CSS is style only. You can't show/hide, move... object without using JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show/hide, move... objects using CSS or HTML only. But you can use JavaScript. Make two divs with `display:none;` one is your div you want to show, and another one is background(`width` and `height` `100%`, `z-index` less than `div` you want to show/hide but more than any other element, and `position:fixed;`) inside `div` that represents background add `onclick="hide()"` and that will call a function `hide()` whenever you click outside your div. And just add function `hide()` that will make both `div`-s disappear.

```js
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("outside").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}

function hide(){
document.getElementById("outside").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#outside{
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:1;
}

#myDiv{
background:red;
width:300px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
display:none;
z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show div</button>
<p><span>some text</span></p>
<p><span>some text</span></p>
<p><span>some text</span></p>
<p><span>some text</span></p>
<p><span>some text</span></p>
<div id="outside" onclick="hide()"></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I have edited my POST, but there is an error. Because it only works once. I didn't understand why ..

Comment: It works. I forgot to add: document.getElementById('chat-threads').classList.toggle('display-settings'); 
in my function : onSettingsChatWindow()

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using just HTML and CSS, but this JavaScript should do it:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#settings-notification')) {
    document.getElementById('chat-threads').classList.toggle('display-
    settings');
  }
}
```

When the user clicks anywhere, the script checks if they have clicked on the div, or on the rest of the page. If it is the rest of the page, then it closes the div.

Comment: I have edited my POST, is this how to do?
Because it only works once.